# Jquery datatable exporting to csv problem with other language

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Japanese characters in my table. If I use excel button for exporting, it works fine but when I do for CSV. The data or the texts is not correct anymore. Do anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Here is my table
[image]

And for exporting to CSV and excel
[image]

I just used the simple way of creating the buttons for export

```
                buttons: [
                      {
                      extend: 'excel',
                      text: 'Export to Excel',
                      className: 'btn btn-default',
                      exportOptions: {
                          columns: ':not(.notexport)'
                      },},
                      {
                      extend: 'csv',
                      text: 'Export to CSV',
                      className: 'btn btn-default',
                      exportOptions: {
                          columns: ':not(.notexport)'
                      },}
                    ],
```

Comment: When you export to CSV, instead of exporting directly to Excel, try exporting to a text file program such as Notepad++. That should handle the UTF-8 characters correctly.

Comment: For Excel, instead of opening the CSV file directly, first save the CSV file todisk, then try launching Excel, and then use the CSV import wizard in Excel: Menu item: Data > from Text/CSV. Using this approach you will see the import wizard where you will have a chance to pick the required character encoding: File Origin "65001 - Unicode (UTF-8)", instead of the default (which for me is Windows 1252).

Comment: yah this works but is there other way you know to make it convenient? since there are some steps in order to transform the text. @andrewjames

Comment: i don't know it's working internally, but i can see that the page has pagination in it, which must means that the data is being fetched in an ajax style to that page, very probably in JSON format. This would be much easier to deal with rather than plucking out elements one by one in the table, but again, if this mechanism doesn't exist.., then this suggestion is stupid.

Comment: I don't know a better way to use a csv file in excel, no. I use the excel export, instead, for this reason.

Comment: Yes its an ajax and JSON format. Any ideas?